# Hosting .net web application in Amazon server

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am planning to host my website in amazon server. I have not much experience in this area. I found that on research, I can use that for free up to 1 year. But I have to submit my card information and so on.

So can I cancel the free account in any time within the period of 1 year ? Do I need to pay any money for that ?

Also is there any alternate option available to host my .net application (for free)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can cancel your AWS subscription any time within a year. You might want to try Azure, as this is native Microsoft cloud solution, so there is some natural integration with c#, .net. Azure gives first 170$ for services for one month, so you can also try some more premium options than in AWS.

**Edit**

Although the response answered to 2 questions that were asked, just some additional clarification:

- yes - one needs to be careful, when choosing the services and choose the ones "eligible for free tier"
- yes - there are additional limitations like storage or 750h of EC2 instance. The overview of limits for free services is specified on: https://aws.amazon.com/free/

There is a bit older reading on this, but gives some perspective on what to look for: https://serverfault.com/questions/326168/what-is-the-true-cost-of-amazons-ec2-free-tier

Comment: Thanks Turo, So if I use AWS , I can cancel anytime within a year and I don't have to pay any money. Right ? Is there any way were they will automatically charge any amount ? like the number of requests per month  or so on?

Comment: Hi Vishnu, you can sign up, they charge like 4$to your credit card, which is then returned after authorization. Just when choosing services make sure to choose the ones "eligible for free tier". This is well marked on AWS. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much Turo.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you signup for a free-tier, doesn't mean you can't accidentally run up hundreds or thousands of dollars on services you didn't mean to.

Its not a free account for a year, it is a certain level of free services. If you exceed those levels, you will be charged.